# Difference between LHD and RHD of $f(x)$ and LHL and RHL of $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus

Say, $f(x)$ =
$\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})  & \mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
  0 & \mbox{if } x=0
 \end{array}
\right.$

Isn't LHD and RHD of $f(x)$ and LHL and RHL of $f'(x)$ same? Say at $x = 0.$

Thanks.

Comment: The question [Continuity of differentiable function $x^2\sin(1/x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212011/continuity-of-differentiable-function-x2-sin1-x) demonstrates that the LHD,RHD of $f(x)$ are in fact $0$ at $x=0$, but the LHL and RHL of $f'(x)$  at $0$ do not exist (the answer only shows that the limit doesn't exist using certain subsequences, but the general statement sort of follows once you see that $\sin , \cos \frac 1x$ oscillates too heavily)

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, $\lim_{a\to x^-} f(a)=f(x)=\lim_{a\to x^+} f(a)$  and $f'(x^-)=f'(x^+)$

At $x=0$ $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)=0=\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$

However, $f'(0^-)$ and $f'(0^+)$ don't exist, since $f'(x)= (2x)\sin{\frac{1}{x}}- \cos{\frac{1}{x}}$ when $x\neq0$.

For $f'(x)$ to be continuous at $x=0$, first it should exist at $x=0$ but it doesn't. So $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

$\mathbf {Edit:}$

No LHL of $f'(x)$ at $x=a$ and $f'(a^-)$ are not same.

$\mathbf {Reason:}$

LHD of $f(x)$ at $x=a$ is $$f'(a^-)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a-h)-f(a)}{-h}$$
LHL of $f'(x)$ at $x=a$ is $$\lim_{x\to a^-} f'(x) = \lim_{x\to a^-} (\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h})$$

You can notice the difference yourself.

Comment: $f'(x)=2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})$

Comment: f'(x) = $2x\  sin \frac{1}{x}\ - cos\frac{1}{x}$ , 

I mean LHD and RHD of f(x) decide the continuity of f'(x) at say x=0. That is, if LHD and RHD of f(x) are same at x=0 then f'(x) = $2x\  sin \frac{1}{x}\ - cos\frac{1}{x}$
 is continuous at x=0?

Comment: @RajeshMarndi For a function to be continuous at some point, not only its left hand limit and right hand limit need to be equal at that point but the limit must also be equal to the value of function at that point.